# Display All Results for this month Only - Unix

Tags: php, sql, unix, unix-timestamp, laravel-5

I have some UNIX time-stamps and I want to display all results for the current month.  When I display the results there is nothing on the view.

```
public static function getArrayMonthly($date_month){

    $currentDate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", '1458086400'));

    $date_month = date('m', $currentDate);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM events where date_start between $currentDate AND $date_month ORDER BY date_start ASC";
    $result = DB::select($sql);

    return($result);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently comparing a timestamp format with a month number so it could not work.

Currently your query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM events where date_start between 1458014400 AND 03 ORDER BY date_start ASC
```

So your date_month should be

```
$first_date_month = strtotime(date('Y-m-01 00:00:00', $currentDate));
$last_date_month = strtotime(date('Y-m-t 23:59:59', $currentDate));
```

Also, in your *between* you have to start with the older date, so it should be like

```
SELECT * FROM events where date_start between $first_date_month AND $last_date_month ORDER BY date_start ASC
```

Comment: This is helpful but I dont wanna stop at the $currentDate.  I want all the results for the entire month.  so that unix timestamp is for today 3-16-2016.  So i Want to display all the results in the month of march

Comment: Ok so you want to show all the result for the first of march until the 31th, whatever the current date is, right? See my edited post